# Inserindo registro duplicado no while do PHP

Tags: php

Estou implantando um sistema, onde o cliente, depois de comprar uma quantidade de créditos, é inserido em sua conta no banco de dados.

Mas estou tendo um problema de duplicação de créditos no meu script PHP.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

include '../../init.php';

$sql = "SELECT *, compras.id_usuario AS id_user_compra, compras.id AS id_compra FROM compras LEFT JOIN creditos ON creditos.id_usuario = compras.id_usuario WHERE compras.entregue = 'nao' AND compras.payment_status = 'Completed'";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);

while ($ln = $query->fetch_array()){
    $id_usuario = $ln['id_user_compra'];
    $id_compra = $ln['id_compra'];
    $creditos = preg_replace("/[^0-9\s]/", "", $ln['item_name']);

    $sql_up = "UPDATE compras SET entregue = 'sim' WHERE id = '$id_compra'";
    $query_up = $mysqli->query($sql_up);

    $sql_ins = "INSERT INTO creditos (id_usuario, credito, debito) VALUES ('$id_usuario', '$creditos', '0')";
    $query_ins = $mysqli->query($sql_ins);
}

?>
```

Nessa minha consulta acima, ele verifica as compras feitas, com as determinadas condições, mas mesmo assim, **às vezes**, ele insere uma compra 2 ou 3x na tabela créditos.

**Imagens para ilustrar:**

*Tabela compras:*

[image: Tabela compras]

*Tabela creditos:*

[image: Tabela creditos]

Como posso corrigir esse problema?

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: O seu `select` deve estar retornando mais de um registro.

Comment: Sim, ele retorna, pois as vezes tem 2 ou 3 compras.

Comment: Então, você está fazendo um `insert` dentro do `while` que percorre os registros. Se houver mais de um, será inserido mais de uma vez.

Comment: Nossa, acabei resolvendo. Dei um LEFT JOIN em outra tabela sem precisar... ficou assim:   `SELECT * FROM compras WHERE compras.entregue = 'nao' AND compras.payment_status = 'Completed'`  Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

No seu select adiciona GROUP BY **IDTABELA** ai não ira trazer registros duplicados.
Exemplo:

```
"SELECT *, compras.id_usuario AS id_user_compra, compras.id AS id_compra FROM compras LEFT JOIN creditos ON creditos.id_usuario = compras.id_usuario WHERE compras.entregue = 'nao' AND compras.payment_status = 'Completed' GROUP BY **IDTABELA**
```